# Cron runs a non-existing variant of . sh script

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, startup

I've been encountered a strange phenomena.

I've been messing with `cron`, so it runs a script called `startup.sh`, which it does.

I used the command `sudo crontab -e` and then entered the following:

```
@reboot sleep 20 && /home/hellfire/startup.sh
```

First I wrote the script to send an email, but later I rewrote it to send a message instead. However, when restarting the server, nothing happened.

Then I checked the status of cron, and was surprised that it had run **the old script**, which now didn't exist anymore. Is there some kind of cron cache?

Here I'm checking the status:

```
hellfire@Plex:~$ sudo systemctl status cron

    ● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-01-20 20:57:56 CET; 1min 45s ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
       Main PID: 537 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 3548)
       CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
               └─537 /usr/sbin/cron -f

    Jan 20 20:57:57 Plex cron[537]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
    Jan 20 20:57:57 Plex cron[537]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
    Jan 20 20:57:57 Plex CRON[565]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uJan 20 20:57:57 Plex CRON[613]: (root) CMD (sleep 20 && /home/hellfire/startup.sh)
    Jan 20 20:58:21 Plex sSMTP[866]: Creating SSL connection to host
    Jan 20 20:58:21 Plex sSMTP[866]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Jan 20 20:58:21 Plex cron[537]: sendmail: 550 5.7.1 Username hellfire@example.se and sender roJan 20 20:58:21 Plex sSMTP[866]: 550 5.7.1 Username hellfire@example.se and sender root@example.seJan 20 20:58:21 Plex CRON[565]: (root) MAIL (mailed 75 bytes of output but got status 0x00                                )
    Jan 20 20:58:21 Plex CRON[565]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

It tried to run the mail script, which don't exist anymore, and it failed (worked before, but that's not the issue)

Then I checked the script file:

```
hellfire@Plex:~$ cat /home/hellfire/startup.sh

#!/bin/bash

smsT --command='m "Adam Larsson" Hellfire are ONLINE'
```

It was the new script, so where did cron run the other (now rewritten script) from?

I've of course restarted Linux, I've even tried to clear the cache, but it don't work..

.. So now I'm confused... (More than normal). Anybody that knows anything as about this?

Running on Ubuntu 18.04.3lts mini

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the crontab you are using. We need to see how cron is running the script. Also, it's always a good idea to tell us what operating system you are using since there can be differences in implementation.

Comment: I didn't know there was more than one crontab, how do I know which one?

Comment: Well, how did you set it up? We need to see the crontab. You must have told cron to run your script somehow right? How? Show us the cron line. And yes, there are many crontabs. Each user has their own, and then you have `/etc/crontab` which is run by root.

Comment: I just used sudo crontab -e

Comment: So you are using root's crontab for some reason. OK, but can you _please show us the crontab_?

Comment: Do you mean this? @reboot sleep 20 && /home/hellfire/startup.sh ? I'm totally new at crontab.

Comment: Yes! Please [edit] your question, explain that you used `sudo -e crontab` to set it up (next time, don't use sudo for this) and include the exact command as you have in the comment. But make sure that's correct. There is no caching, so what you describe doesn't make much sense. Perhaps you have other crontabs running?

Comment: Is there any way to kill and remove all crontab (s), maybe it's easier to do that and reinstall fresh..  alt how can I see which crontabs are running, any log files available?

Comment: Crontabs are stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`. As a *root* user, go to this directory and look at the contents of the files where each file is the crontab of the respective user.

Comment: Are you sure this is happening? The `systemctl` output you show is from yesterday, and this script runs on reboot. Are you sure that this happened _after_ you changed the script? What happens if you reboot your machine now? Do you still see the old script being run?

Comment: I'm very sure this is happening. I've just rebooted, and the same result: Jan 21 15:51:50 Plex cron[576]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jan 21 15:51:50 Plex cron[576]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jan 21 15:51:50 Plex CRON[582]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uJan 21 15:51:50 Plex CRON[626]: (root) CMD (sleep 20 && /home/hellfire/startup.sh)  ...cut.. the same.. but today's date.. there must be some other file , but I've searched..

Comment: I can see no evidence of cron running the old script. Could you point it out to me? What I see is that the cron daemon tries to send the output of a script to somebody.  Output from cronjobs is usually mailed to the user of the job.

Comment: @Kusalananda as you can see, it points to the startup.sh file.  It is not supposed to send anything by mail, those addresses don't even exist.

Comment: Yes, it points to the `startup.sh` script because you have told `cron` to run it at startup.  As far as I can make out from your question, you have not actually changed the cronjob itself, only the contents of the script. You keep saying your script is `/home/hellfire/startup.sh`, and that this is the new script.  It is the same script that you scheduled at the start, right?, but the contents is different, you've changed it? Does the script produce output, or errors? If it does, the cron daemon will try to email that output to the owner of the job.

Comment: If the old script sent a message to `hellfire@example.se`, then it's also not strange that this message is still in the message queue if it's undeliverable.  It will probably stay there until the mail system drops it in a few days.

Comment: I'm seeing your point, and I'm ready to anything to fix this, any suggestions how to see/reset any que?  And the script works standalone. I even copied the working script to startup2.sh, and added that line to cron, now it shows the send error twice..

Comment: I think @Kusalananda it right, that it's cron that tries to send a mail, due to some error, but shouldn't cron be able to run a script that works in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic "*chase your own tail*" issue.

If a cron job strikes on an error, cron will send an email from the user account it's current running on, to the email specified in the current mail Configuration on the system.

Since the first script was notification via email, I assumed (a faulty assumption) that cron was running some strange "ghost copy" of the script, but it was just doing it's job.

It was @kusalananda that got me on the right track.

What I find curious, and the reason for me to write this as an answer, is that cron never said that anything was wrong with the new script, except that it couldn't send an email.
A little moment 22, where the focus was placed on the wrong issue.

This is of course not the optimal answer, but this time it was a **sbk** error (**S**tupid **B**ehind **K**eyboard)...

So a lesson learnt, and maybe a tips to others, to always keep an eye open for the information that isn't present in a case..